# Use the MSChart in the Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, mschart

I use the MSChart in the web part, it works fine. But there is a problem.

I add some controls in the Web Part Editor to configure the MSChart's color. Everytime after I change the color of the Chart, then click the Apply button, it does not show the change. You need click twice or refresh the page again. Does anyone meet the same problem?

Best Regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the changes are only applied after a refresh of the page or multiple button clicks, you might have some problems with the WebPart life cycle. You should solve the problem by debugging you WebPart step by step.

For more information about the WebPart life cycle have a look at the following links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366536.aspx
- http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2007/07/24/asp-net-webpart-life-cycle-reminder.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/WebPartLifeCycle.aspx
- http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/understanding-web-part-life-cycle/